# Making all combinations of 1 and 0. Code works well in java but not in js

Tags: javascript, java, combinations

Since the same code is working well in Java, there shouldn't be a logical problem. They are exactly same.

Java code:

```
public class ZeroOneGen {
  public static void ZeroOneGen(int[] dataArr, int digits, int index) {
    if (index == digits) {
      String str = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
        str = str + dataArr[i];
      }
      System.out.println(str);
      return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      dataArr[index] = i;
      ZeroOneGen(dataArr, digits, index + 1);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] dataArrTemp = new int[3];
    ZeroOneGen(dataArrTemp, 3, 0);
  }
}
```

Output:
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

JS code:

```js
function ZeroOneGen(dataArr, digits, index) {
  if (index == digits) {
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
      str = str + dataArr[i];
    }
    console.log(str);
    return;
  }

  for (z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
    dataArr[index] = z;
    ZeroOneGen(dataArr, digits, index + 1);
  }

} // end function

var dataArrTemp = new Array(3);
ZeroOneGen(dataArrTemp, 3, 0);
```

output: 000 001
I expect it to continue and print other combinations as well. It stops at 001.

Comment: if `(index == digits)`  is true, it'll exit the function with `return` remove it and it should continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `i` and `z` because if not, you get global variables and this destroys iterating with recursive functions.

To prevent this and [for getting an error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors), you could add [`'strict mode';`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) at the beginning of the code.

Please have a look to the link, because it changes some other parts as well.

```js
function ZeroOneGen(dataArr, digits, index) {
    var i, z;
    if (index == digits) {
        var str = "";
        for (i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
            str = str + dataArr[i];
        }
        console.log(str)
        return;
    }

    for (z = 0; z < 2; z++) {
        dataArr[index] = z;
        ZeroOneGen(dataArr, digits, index + 1);
    }
}

var dataArrTemp = new Array(3);
ZeroOneGen(dataArrTemp, 3, 0);
```